# What is the Meaning of this specific icon of my Visual Studio form in my class library project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a class Library output project and my main issue is that frmMain.Designer.cs as an right arrow as an icon as the attached screen shot. I have not see this before on any project and what is the meaning of this icon?
[image]

Comment: It is the standard icon for an auto-generated file.  Look under Properties > Resources.resx for another example, the Resources.Designer.cs is an auto-generated file as well.  Their content is controlled by the IDE, triggered when you double-click their parent node.  Shows the designer for that particular resource.  You must never change these files yourself since those changes will be lost when you use the designer.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a "Type Forwarding" symbol.

[Class View and Object Browser Icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN)